# Is Jasper Report tool available in Netbeans?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, netbeans-plugins

I am working on a java project and it is about creating an IDE where programs would be stored in a encrypted form. I need a reporting tool and as far as I have searched over the internet, I think Jasper Reports would be good. I wanted to ask if I would need to download some software like Jaspersoft?

Or is it like some tool for running Jasper Reports files, that is, .jrxml files is already included in Netbeans IDE?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to download iReport Plugin for Netbeans then you can start designing .jrxml.
download it from [here](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/4425/ireport) or you can go for separate [iReport Designer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ireport/) which is standalone designer.

Answer (score 0):

Jaspersoft has a designer called iReport Designer that is a Netbeans based app.  You can also get it as a Netbeans plugin from here:

http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=4425